# How to create a guided tour for an android application

Tags: android

A couple of months ago I bought myself an HTC ONE X. I admired they way they guide the user in taking his first steps in the phone with interactive widgets and help functions.

I would like to add this kind of functionality to Rogerthat, the app we are building, but I wonder if there are tools / libraries that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

Roman Nurik put together a library called "Wizard Pager" to do this sort of thing. It could likely be used to do what you're asking.

https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/6cVymZvn3f4

http://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/wizardpager

Update:

I think this might also be helpful to you. It's similar to the tour shown when first running a stock Android rom in ICS+.

The library can be used in any version of Android:

https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

If you want consecutive showcases you can look at this expansio:

https://github.com/blundell/ShowcaseViewExample

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5):

I did a guided tour for my app that allows the user to navigate through 4 note pages ans see the instructions. Here's the code:

```
public static void tour(final Context context, final String title, final int pageNumber, 
                        final Drawable icon, final String[] pageMessage, final int[] layouts, final ViewGroup root) {
    Builder tourDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    int nPage = 0;


    if (pageMessage!=null){
        tourDialog.setMessage(pageMessage[pageNumber]);
        nPage = pageMessage.length;
    }

    if (layouts!=null){         
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout1 = inflater.inflate(layouts[pageNumber], root);
        tourDialog.setView(layout1);
        //tourDialog.setView(views[pageNumber]);
        nPage = layouts.length;
    }


    tourDialog.setTitle(title+" (page "+(pageNumber+1)+"/"+nPage+")");

    tourDialog.setPositiveButton("Prev",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    tour(context, title,  pageNumber-1, icon, pageMessage,layouts, root);
                    return;
                }
            });


    tourDialog.setNeutralButton("Next",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    tour(context, title,  pageNumber+1, icon, pageMessage,layouts, root);
                    return;
                }
            });
    tourDialog.setNegativeButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    return;
                }
            });
    if (icon!=null)
        tourDialog.setIcon(icon);
    AlertDialog dialog = tourDialog.create();

    dialog.show();

    if (pageNumber==0)
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
    else if (pageNumber==nPage-1){
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setEnabled(false); 
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
int[] layout = {R.layout.note1, R.layout.note2, R.layout.note3, R.layout.note4}; //resource id of each page's layout
tour(context, "Notes ", 0,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gmpte_logo_25px),null, layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root));
```

and an example of note page layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/root"
  android:padding="10dip">

<TextView android:id="@+id/text_before"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          android:textSize="16dp"
          android:text="@string/note1_before_text"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
          android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
          android:src="@drawable/mylocation_blue"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_before"
          />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_after"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_before"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:text="@string/note1_after_text"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to write your own layout for each note page, but use the same id (`android:id="@+id/root"`) for the root layout in each page.

Comment: I'm not really looking for dialogs but more for small help texts with arrows pointing to user interface elements.

Answer (score 3):

The [Showcase View Library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) is definitely what you want:

[image: Show case view lib]

Comment: Hello, how do you set up a "ShowCase library" on a button?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewPager and a fragment to show your help screens. You'll find plenty information about that.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote little library
That contains a simple component for making ​​a app tour.
It`s very restricted to my case but  maybe could be your case .
Single LessonCardView Showed onstartactivity for the first time
or  on button click 
Any criticism ,help or advice will be  appreciated. thanks
https://github.com/dnocode/DnoLib

Answer (score 0):

You can try TourGuide http://worker8.github.io/TourGuide

It's fairly up-to-date (uses Kotlin 1.2) and works pretty nicely.

Most of the alternatives I've checked recently (in 2021), are either not working or buggy.

TourGuide is not perfect (it's been 3 years since it's last commit), and the maintainer doesn't seem to respond to PRs or issues.