# How to show a simple guide to user on how to use particular functionality of app in transparent screen in android?

Tags: android

I want to guide user to using particular section of app in a transparent screen with a "GOT IT!" button to confirm that they saw this tip. Like the one, app like Zapya uses to guide user to choose between "create group" and "join" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the following thread for some ideas:

[How to create a guided tour for an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477594/how-to-create-a-guided-tour-for-an-android-application)

I think that the [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) library fits your purposes quite well.

Comment: thanks a lot, you know some way to do this below api level 11 ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that ShowcaseView has supported lower API levels a few years ago. You could look at the [release or commit history](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/releases) to download an older version and go from there. Another library that could be useful for you is [RoboDemo](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo), that supports API levels 7 and up. If you need really simple showcase features it could be worth developing it yourself to fit your needs. Just take one of the projects as an example and roll out your own implementation.